# Electric potential of points using scipy and distance

Tags: python, scipy

I would like to write a function for the formula 5.5.1 on this page:

[Electric potential of point charges](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_University_Physics_(OpenStax)/Map%3A_University_Physics_II_-_Thermodynamics%2C_Electricity%2C_and_Magnetism_(OpenStax)/5%3A_Electric_Charges_and_Fields/5.5%3A_Calculating_Electric_Fields_of_Charge_Distributions)

I found [scipy.spatial.distance](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html)

There is the euclidean distance with the weight function, which I could use but there is also a squareform and a sqeuclidean.

I am new to scipy, so I either have to test this out or leverage on someone with experience.

Are these three versions basically equivalent for my use case or should I chose one over the other. On the long run I want to calculate a large amount of points (in the range of millions) so performance and memory usage will matter here.

Comment: maybe you could share some minimal code example, on how you implemented eq. 5.5.1 so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy would be sufficient for this problem. This formula could be easily vectorized, 
so you don't need to use Python loops to compute it, e.g.

```
import numpy as np

def get_electric_potential(x, qi, ri):
    """
    x = (x1, x2, x3) -- numpy array of shape 3x1

    qi = (q1, ..., qN) -- numpy array of shape (N,)

    ri = (...).shape = 3 x N
    """
    eps0 = 0.00001 # Put your value here!!!
    C = 1 / 4 / np.pi / eps0
    C = 1  # Comment this line
    return C * ((qi / np.diag((x - ri).T @ (x - ri))) * (x - ri)).sum(axis=1)
```

So, `x` is a vector, where you want to compute value of the potential;
`ri` is a matrix of shape 3xN, each column of it represent location of electric charge. `qi` -- corresponding vector of electric charges.

Example:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3])[:, np.newaxis]
ri = np.arange(30).reshape(3, 10)
qi = np.arange(10)
get_electric_potential(x, qi, ri)
```

> array([-0.28622007, -0.83010791, -1.37399575])

Note: to use this formula you need to define constant C, define eps0.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thanks a lot, that gives me the jumpstart I needed.